# Sum every last value with all previous values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of some values which I need to convert to new array and sum every value with all previous values. For example (array length, keys and values always differ), this is what I have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 3
    [9] => 1
)
```

and this is what I need:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 9
    [7] => 10
    [8] => 13
    [9] => 14
)
```

I tried many different ways but always stuck at something or realized that I'm wrong somewhere. I have a feeling that I'm trying to reinvent a wheel here, because I think there have to be some simple function for this, but had no luck with finding solution. This is last way I tried:

```
$array = array( "0"=> 1, "1"=> 1, "2"=> 5, "3"=> 1, "4"=> 1, "7"=> 1, "8"=> 3, "9"=> 1 );
$this = current($array);
$next = next($array);
$end = next(end($array));
$sum = 0;
$newArray = array();

foreach ($array as $val){
    if($val != $end){
        $sum = ($this += $next);
        array_push($newArray, $sum);
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

..unfortunately wrong again. I spend lot of time finding ways how not to get where I need to be, can someone kick me into right direction, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suggest you to use `array_slice()` & `array_sum()`

```
$array = array( "0"=>1,"1"=>1,"2"=>5,"3"=>1,"4"=>1,"7"=>1,"8"=>3,"9"=>1);
$keys = array_keys($array);
$array = array_values($array);

$newArr = array();

foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
    $newArr[] = array_sum(array_slice($array, 0, $key+1));
}
$newArr = array_combine($keys, $newArr);

print '<pre>';
print_r($newArr);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 9
    [7] => 10
    [8] => 13
    [9] => 14
)
```

Reference:

- [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)
- [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)
- [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)
- [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: you are calculating array sum and slice over and over again for values you allready know the sum from the prev calculation... and no need to slice and array sum ... this will consume memory and cpu for nothing...

Comment: Thank you! This is doing exactly what i need, I use those (non consecutive) indexes to pair this output with another array.

Answer (score 4):

let assume your array variable is $a;
You can use simple for loop

```
    for($i=1;$i<sizeof($a);$i++)
    {
        $a[$i]=$a[$i]+$a[$i-1];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just go over the array sum and add to a new array (in a simple way):

```
$array = array( "0"=> 1, "1"=> 1, "2"=> 5, "3"=> 1, "4"=> 1, "7"=> 1, "8"=> 3, "9"=> 1 );
var_dump($array);
$newArray = array();

$sum = 0;
foreach ($array as $a){
  $sum += $a;
  $newArray[]=$sum;
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sums = array_reduce($array, function (array $sums, $num) {
    return array_merge($sums, [end($sums) + $num]);
}, []);
```

In other words, this iterates over the array (`array_reduce`) and in each iteration appends (`array_merge`) a number to a new array (`$sums`) which is the sum of the previous item in the array (`end($sums)`) and the current number. Uses PHP 5.4+ array syntax (`[]`).

Comment: Neat solution although a little explanation could help less experienced people to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You complicated too much. Loop trough all elements of array and add current element to sum. Then assign that sum to new array.

```
$array = array( "0"=> 1, "1"=> 1, "2"=> 5, "3"=> 1, "4"=> 1, "7"=> 1, "8"=> 3, "9"=> 1 );

$sum = 0;
$newArray = array();

foreach ($array as $key=>$val){
    $sum += $val;
    $newArray[$key]=$sum;
}
```

Make sure to get indexes right.

Comment: Do you mean `$sum+=$val`? I think its wrong `$sum+=$sum;`